# A type "'text'" does not exist? - TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I've got an error message in TYPO3 7.4.

> 'Found an invalid element type declaration in %s. A type \"'text'\" does not exist.'

Looks like the quotation marks at `text` are somehow doubled, but I have no idea where this possibly could be and/or how to solve this.
I can post more of the error message if needed, just thought that this part is the most important one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that somewhere in your `Controller`, `Model` or `Repository` a PHPDoc has a wrong type declaration like:

```
class Example {

    /**
     * @var text
     */
    protected $someProperty = '';

    /**
     * Foo
     *
     * @param text $bar
     * @return text
     */
    protected function foo($bar) {
        return '';
    }

}
```

Please change "text" to "string", clear all caches and try it again!

Comment: Thanks, I found it. Was inside the Model